# SQL statement not doing quite what i would like it to do

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I am currently writing a SQL query in SQL Server Management Studio that will be used in PHP

The query is meant to get all of the records between 8AM and 8 PM yesterday and count how many of the records have the `fffffff0` as the `CardID` currently this just spits out 355 records with the column `CardCOUNT` just having the number one in them not quite what I want, how should I do this?

```
SELECT 
   COUNT(CardID) AS CardCOUNT,
   ReaderTime,
   controllerID,
   dtReading
FROM 
   myMachineMonitor2.dbo.ReaderData
WHERE 
   (controllerID = 31)
   AND (ReaderTime BETWEEN '08:00:00' AND '20:00:00')
   AND (CardID = 'fffffff0')
   AND (DATEDIFF(DAY, DATEADD(DAY, - 1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), dtReading) = 0)
GROUP BY 
   ReaderTime, controllerID, dtReading
```

After playing around with it I kinda figured it out here is what I came up with

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(CardID) AS CardCOUNT
FROM 
    myMachineMonitor2.dbo.ReaderData
WHERE 
    (controllerID = 31)
    AND (ReaderTime BETWEEN '08:00:00' AND '20:00:00')
    AND (CardID = 'fffffff0')
    AND (DATEDIFF(DAY, DATEADD(DAY, - 0, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), dtReading) = 0)
```

Comment: You should specify the type of the ReaderTime column...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This changes the logic to just working with the current date:

```
SELECT COUNT(CardID) AS CardCOUNT, ReaderTime, controllerID, dtReading
FROM myMachineMonitor2.dbo.ReaderData
WHERE (controllerID = 31) AND
      (CardID = 'fffffff0') AND
      dtReading >= cast(cast(getdate() as date) as datetime) - 16.0/24 and
      dtReading >= cast(cast(getdate() as date) as datetime) - 4.0/24
GROUP BY ReaderTime, controllerID, dtReading ;
```

The cast to `date` puts the value at midnight.  Then it subtracts 16 and 4 hours for the range.

This expression also does all the work on the current date.

Comment: The change on `dtReading` does however change the semantics. You probably meant `=` (for just yesterday) rather than `>=` (for anything since yesterday).

Comment: @jcaron . . . I misunderstood the question and so revised the answer.

Comment: @Gordon linoff  i just tried your query and it's doing the same thing mine was asin just putting 1 in the count insted of the total number also it has today on it, what i want is Yesterday between 8am and 8pm the one you wrote goes from about 1600 ish yesterday to now

Comment: @Oisian2 . . . I think I revised the query since you ran it.  Try this version.

Comment: @GordonLinoff the new version runs from 1600 yesterday to now , what i want is yesterday between 8 am and 8 pm, also i need it to count how many there are so say there are 500 records i need it to say 500 and not just 500 records that just say 1 in the column like it currently does

Answer (score 1):

I know there are some debates about the sargability of datetime columns but I would approach this more like this. I find this a lot easier to understand by separating the two conditions.

```
SELECT COUNT(CardID) AS CardCOUNT
    , ReaderTime
    , controllerID
    , dtReading
FROM myMachineMonitor2.dbo.ReaderData
WHERE controllerID = 31
    AND CardID = 'fffffff0' 
    AND ReaderTime >= dateadd(hour, 8, dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - 1, 0)) --8am yesterday
    AND ReaderTime < dateadd(hour, 19, dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - 1, 0)) --9pm yesterday
GROUP BY ReaderTime
    , controllerID
    , dtReading;
```

Comment: Hi @SeanLange i tried this version and it's not outputting anything at all :(

Comment: What predicates are causing nothing to be returned? It is impossible for me to debug this but this should work based on your original post.

Comment: What are the datatypes of these columns? That could very well be the issue too.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is by making time a grouping condition you are forcing one line per distinct time, not allowing an aggregate over a range of times. Just drop the times from your GROUP BY and you're fine.

```
SELECT controllerID, COUNT(CardID) AS CardCOUNT
FROM myMachineMonitor2.dbo.ReaderData
WHERE (controllerID = 31)
  AND (ReaderTime BETWEEN '08:00:00' AND '20:00:00')
  AND (CardID = 'fffffff0')
  AND (DATEDIFF(DAY, DATEADD(DAY, - 1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), dtReading) = 0)
GROUP BY controllerID
```